# Хуки, Кастомные хуки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

```
import useHook from "./hook";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setV] = useHook("text");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value);
      setV();
    }
  }, [value, setV]);

  return null;
}
```

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useHook = (text) => {
  const [value, setvalue] = useState("value");

  console.log(text);

  const setV = () => {
    setvalue("newValue");
  };

  return [value, setV];
};

export default useHook;
```

Помогите разобраться!

2 вопроса:

1. Получается при вызове setV из App, в кастомном хуке происходит setState, соответственно, я думаю, что происходит повторный запуск этого кастомного хука - так вот, откуда он при повторном вызове узнает про значение своего параметра, ведь явно параметр мы передавали при первом его вызове, в компоненте App.
2. получается же возвращаемый setV из кастомного хука - это же новая функция. Так почему не происходит бесконечный рендеринг?

Comment: не понял первый вопрос. Попробуй его понятнее сформулировать

Comment: по поводу второго: бесконечным рендеринг был бы, если бы изменение зависимости приводило к новому рендерингу, но в текущем коде этого нет, так как устанавливается константа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. useState хранит в себе данные предыдущего рендера, а если рендер первый, то получает данные из defaultValue (в твоем случае - "text"). Т.е. при ререндере useState запомнит своё значение из предыдущего рендер и использует его, игнорируя новые defaultValue
2. Бесконечного ререндера нет, потому что это простые данные. Опишу цикл работы для наглядности:

> -> Mount
>
> -> setV
>
> -> setState from "text" to "newValue"
>
> -> didMount
>
> -> Mount
>
> -> setV
>
> -> setState from "newValue" to "newValue" (вот тут реакт увидит, что prevStateValue == newStateValue, поэтому не будет ререндерить дум)
>
> -> Render end

Если ты сделаешь то же самое, но вместо строки будешь использовать число (к примеру count = 1, а в setV - count += 1, то ререндер будет бесконечным)